# How to continue the python script execution from the point it left before reboot

Tags: python, reboot

I want to write a test script in python which should reboot the system in between the test execution on local machine... (No remote automation server is monitoring the script). How the script execution can be made continuous even after reboot? The script covers following scenario...

1. Create a Volume on some disk
2. Create a filesystem and mount the file system temporary
3. Reboot the system
4. Verify if filesystem is mounted
5. Mount the filesystem again.

Comment: What OS is the machine running?

Answer (score 3):

It's not about python but rather about your whole system config. In given conditions I suggest you to split your script on 2 parts. First part is doing 1..3 and storing some extra info you're required onto persistent storage other than the fs you're experimenting on. The second part is invoked on each OS os start, reads some data stored by first part and then performs checking actions 4..5. It seems to be the most obvious and simple way.

Comment: Split into multiple scripts is a workaround which I am already doing. The example is just for understanding the reboot required somewhere in the middle of script. The scenario could be different where I may require to verify many variables stored before reboot, where I don't want to store the data somewhere in text file or database..

Comment: Is pickle object helpful for achieving this objective... HOW?

Comment: pickle is a way to serialize your data into binary files. In given case I'd suggest some text format (json or ConfigParse libraries).

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni were you able to get a python script to do the task?